# Firebase push notification iOS in codenameone

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, codenameone

i have been configured iOS push notification with Firebase, and i want to:

- add my existing configuration called in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions(AppDelegate) to native call in my codenameone project.
- make a native call with codenameOne of overriding fonctions (didReceiveNotificationResponse, willPresentNotification, didReceiveRegistrationToken)existing in Firebase Pods.

And i have one issue with registration notification when i make a native call for configuration firebase in codenameone project and build it, and this is the error returned in Xcode:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIApplication registerForRemoteNotifications]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1fccaaed0'
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: We don't officially support firebase for iOS push so I have no experience with that. Having said that there's a link to a discussion here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3060 that might help you